# mySQL Force Not Null using Query or phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, notnull

Im using XAMP with mySQL and phpMyAdmin.

I cant seem to work out how to set a column to NOT NULL in php my admin..

How do i do this?

Is there a quick way to set all columns not to be null in mySQL?

I havve tried: `ALTER TABLE flights
CHANGE FlightID NOT NULL;`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to issue an ALTER TABLE statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name [data type] NOT NULL,
MODIFY column_name_2 [data type] NOT NULL,
...
MODIFY column_name_x [data type] NOT NULL
```

Note that `[data type]` here is of course the data type of your column (i.e. `VARCHAR(255)` or whatever)

Just list all the columns you want to modify in this single statement.

Comment: Do you need to specify the datatype?

Comment: I get this error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''flights' MODIFY 'FlightID' int(6) NOT NULL, MODIFY 'AircraftID' int(6) NOT ' at line 1"

Comment: @Lmc Yes you need to specify the data type

Comment: @LmC Don't use single quotes around your database object names (table name, column names).  You should use backticks.

Comment: Ahhh sorry! Ill give it a try